# string URLs of images in the database and don't show image in jsp file

Tags: database, string, image, jsp, show

I use MySql database.  There are string url of images in database.I want to show images in jsp file but I can't. My code is here.

```
<c:forEach var="urun" items="${listUrun.rows}">
            <tr>  
             <td><c:out value="${urun.kitapresim}" /></td>
         <img src="<c:url value="${urun.kitapresim}" /> " width="270" height="190"/>
```

Jsp file looks like it .

http://i.hizliresim.com/Ez6dM8.png

How  I solved it?

Comment: is that valid JSP code?

Comment: Sorry; I forgot finally </tr> and </c:forEach> tag in screenshot . But The logic of this code.

Comment: Have you viewed the html source to see what kind of values you're getting for the image paths?

Answer (score 0):

You have double quotation here

```
  <img src="<c:url value="${urun.kitapresim}" /> " width="270" height="190"/>
```

replace it with `''`

```
<img src="<c:url value='${urun.kitapresim}' /> " width="270" height="190"/>
```

or escape it.

```
<img src="<c:url value=\"${urun.kitapresim}\" /> " width="270" height="190"/>
```